# Service running in Docker returning URLs to another service service in different container

Tags: docker, docker-network

I'm very new to Docker so it might just be I've misunderstood something. We are developing a system using an SDK, this SDK relies on 2 Docker services for which we have the tar files of the images. Both these images expose a REST API on port 8080.

I've got containers running as per the instructions we were provided. The SDK connects to one service (A), and service A uses service B. One of the options provided when running A is a URL for connecting to B.

The URL I used is then `http://service-b-container-name:8080` (as specified in the provided instructions)

It seems like then the API on service A is returning URLs for resources on service B and then the SDK in our application (running on the host) is attempting to connect directly to service A. This then fails because I've exposed service A on different port (since service B was exposed on 8080, I used 8081 for service A) but also the host cannot resolve `service-b-container-name`.

I was able to get it running by swapping the exposed ports and adding `service-b-container-name` to my host's `hosts` files to resolve to 127.0.0.1, however needing to do this seems really wrong.

Is there something I can do about it or is it that the service is wrong for returning URLs to another service?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the SDK receives from service A the URL to reach service B at `http://localhost:8080/...` because when service B is asked for the URL of a resource it gives this IP:port to the client (service A, in this case) because the service is really serving the resource on this URL (inside the container).

If you want to change this behaviour, so the SDK can access to service B through port 8081, you should change on which port service B is exposed inside the container too. So when the service B is asked for a resource, it will answer that it resource is on some URL on port 8081.

About that the host cannot resolve `service-b-container-name`, the only ones who can reach service B through that name are services on the same docker networks than service B. Host can reach docker services and containers through bound ports.

Hope it helped ;)